# How do i make Text to Speech with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

Like the question title, i am a newbie with NAudio and i want to make a Text to Speech demo with NAudio.
Can NAudio do that.
Please give me some suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: can you please try this, https://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: i see that all of demos are from wav file or mp3 file, so i  dont know that NAudio can make sound from the text.

Answer (score 1):

No, NAudio does not provide text to speech. You should use [SpeechSynthesizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx) for that

Comment: I wrote a C library that can make the wave data from the text. In that library i have an A function that each time i call A(), i can take 2000 byte(wave sine data) from the text. Its difficult to describe what i want but can i use the Read fuction of IWaveProvider to archieve this. Each time i only have 2000 bytes, for example i will have total 10000 bytes from the text. Each time i want to take into the buffer only 2000bytes, when the waveout read and the buffer prepare running out(1800th byte),i will add more 2000. Can i do it withNAudio. Please give me some suggestions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Install naudio package from nugget and then use below code:

```
IWaveProvider provider = null;
var stream = new MemoryStream();
using (var synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    synth.SetOutputToAudioStream(stream,
        new SpeechAudioFormatInfo(44100, AudioBitsPerSample.Sixteen, AudioChannel.Mono));
    synth.Speak(textToSpeak);

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(stream, new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1));
}

waveOut.Init(provider);
waveOut.Play();
while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```